# res.json returning unintentionally modified input

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

My res.json function seems to be modifying my data. If I log the data in the function it returns the proper data. Only inside res.json does my data change and I can't figure out why.

For ex. Instead of returning `{"unix":"1484600306","naturalFormat":"2017-01-16"}` it returns `{"unix":"1484600306","naturalFormat":"\"2017-01-16\""}.`

function:

```
function unixToDate(timestamp) {
  var a = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  //console.log(a);
  var rgx = /T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{3})Z/;
  var newA = JSON.stringify(a);
  //console.log(newA.replace(rgx, ""));
  return newA.replace(rgx, "");
}
```

route

```
router.get('/:unix', function(req, res) {
  var timestamp = req.params.unix;
  var regex = new RegExp("\\d{10}");
  if (regex.test(timestamp)) {
    var date = unixToDate(timestamp);
    console.log(date);
    res.json({ unix : timestamp, naturalFormat : date });
  } else {
    res.json({ unix: null, naturalFormat : null});
  }
});
```

Again i'm a newb with regex and if I had to guess it would have something to do with that.

PS I didn't use toString() because my date was coming out wrong i.e 11/30/2015 instead of 12/01/2015 so that's why I did it this way with regex.

Thank you!

Comment: This is an XY problem. Do not hack your way around the Date object. Use momentjs for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `unixToDate`, here:

```
var newA = JSON.stringify(a);
```

You're serializing a Date as JSON, which means `newA` will be a string like this: `"2017-01-16T00:00:000.000Z"`, *including* the quotation marks. Then, when you call `res.json`, it serializes that string again, quotation marks and all.

The simplest fix is to use [`Date.prototype.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) instead. It will return the same string as the above, without the quotation marks:

```
var newA = a.toISOString();
```

In fact, your method of removing the time part of the date with `String.prototype.replace` is a bit convoluted. ISO 8601 dates always have the same number of digits in each position, so why not just use `String.prototype.slice`?

```
function unixToDate(timestamp) {
  var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: Great!! I value @amberlamps suggestion but I needed to know what I was doing wrong. Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Moment.js is awesome. It's also often overkill.